# Should I use my dupehammer superpowers to close a question about things I have no idea but OP said it's a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, privileges, dupehammer, tag-badges

I have [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) dupehammer superpowers.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26942674/1529630) has [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag, but it's about [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs), about which I have no idea.

The question was flagged as a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22066919/1529630) by @m59.

OP seems to agree it's a duplicate, because he said

> Thank you! Great solution. @m59

Should I use my close superpowers, even if I'm not sure if it's a duplicate because I don't know AngularJS?

Similarly, I have no idea about Grunt, but the asker of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26940073/1529630) edited it to add

> There's actually an anwser [sic] to my question. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696148/grunt-how-to-watch-and-synchronize-files-deletion).

Sorry if I should have asked this question before closing this one.

Comment: Hmm... can you now answer your own question based on what you know about the community?

Comment: I can't judge, like you. But I don't think it makes sense to use a dupehammer, you have to got as an experienced user, for something of which you have no idea, who knows if the user has the experience to judge it and even when he does not have the ability to close or worse to use the dupehammer.

Comment: Superhammer or not, one should always only vote for something if one is sure of it. And if not yourself somebody else here must have the sufficient knowledge. Also maybe one can judge if two questions are duplicates even if one does not have the full knowledge about the topic. I would not fully trust the OP. I have seen people mark answers as solving the question which did not solve the question, so I would guess there are also people who agree to a duplicate although it isn't, although I have never seen such a case actually.

Comment: Seems to me that the dupehammer should be optional.  In other words, when a person with the dupehammer superpower votes to close, the system should ask whether the intent is a normal vtc or a dupehammer vtc. That way you could cast a normal vtc on questions that you aren't 100% sure about.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not sure if I'm fully convinced by my own first reaction, but I present it for voting:

Suppose you didn't have dupehammer. Would you vote to close as dupe based on the (apparent) opinion of the OP that it is? If not, of course don't dupehammer it.

If so, then you should vote to close despite having dupehammer, for two reasons:

1. dupehammer was probably not intended to *remove* from badge-winners the ability to legitimately mark dupes. Rather the reverse: the intention is that if a dupehammer-wielder (which you are) is convinced that the question is a dupe (which you are, albeit not on the basis of your domain knowledge), then other people should not have their time wasted any further. So don't waste their time any further.
2. Stack Exchange, not you, made the decision to change the conditions for a question to be marked as a duplicate. The conditions are met. Let the system play out. I'd guess that the majority of dupehammer-wielders have been surprised at least once when they failed to anticipate that a particular vote would be a hammer. It's not supposed to matter or affect how we vote. This is not our problem to worry about.

A minor third point, that's not a reason so much as a mitigation: anything you do can be undone. If you're wrong, and it's not a dupe, then your error was to think it was a dupe (and this is an error that dupehammer-wielders will occasionally make), not to say so given that you did.

Comment: I'm a fan of "let the system play out." If the OP protests or someone disagrees with you, others can reverse your vote. The dupehammer just means that you being wrong is like five people being wrong. That happens sometimes too.

Comment: Bad answer - expanded privileges means expanded responsibility to use them with care.  Yes, mistakes can be undone - but when one individual's vote is worth several other people's, using it without a similar ratio of increased consideration results in wasting everyone's time.  The fact that the *asker* thinks it is a dupe changes the calculation a bit in this case, but that doesn't seem to be a factor in your conclusion.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: thing is, nobody with dupehammer power asked for it, and there's no indication in advance of casting the vote whether it will kick in or not (you have to check the tags of the question *and* give a flying hoot about badges). It's not a "privilege", it's just something that happens to you. You may be right that it would best be used with more care than an ordinary close vote. But the UI doesn't support that, that is to say the StackExchange software (as opposed to this Stack Overflow community in particular) has decreed that it cannot be used with care.

Answer (score 44):

I think it's better to leave the post alone. Using your privilege to mark a post duplicate when you are not fully certain that the question is a duplicate is an abuse of the privilege. You could leave a comment indicating that the question is potentially a duplicate. You'll have to trust that other users that are certain that the question is a duplicate will exercise their privileges and will vote to mark the question as a duplicate.

Comment: I always figure - if you don't know, then leave it. Someone who does know won't be far behind! (Although, I do wish that some of the 'superpowers' had a lower power level)

Answer (score 11):

Provided the OP has given a very strong signal I don't see the harm in this, because in the majority of cases it will be correct. In the event it wasn't correct it's still easy enough to reopen (worst case is a mod flag+explain). Close as duplicate isn't a permanent state (unlike a merge, which is *much* harder to get reversed), it can be reversed by the community even.

I don't find it abusive at all, I'd tend to look at it more as your vote being a proxy/gateway/check+balance for a [binding close as duplicate OP vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172016/153020), a feature that doesn't exist, but does seem to have strong community endorsement.

Obviously use some judgement, even if it's not directly your area of expertise. If the message from the OP is buried in comments or an NAA answer you're possibly even more likely to make the right call than people seeing just the questions in /review.

It's more wrong to have text in a question that says "found solution here" or similar than it is to take an OP at their word for something that's in all likelihood an accurate assessment.

Answer (score 9):

That's actually better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/ :D.

*When voting to close, you should be something like 95% sure (YMMV). There are* n *votes needed to close a question. Compute the probability that a question gets closed by mistake...*

Now seriously: You're maybe 5 times stronger than a normal voter, so allow yourself a 5 times lower error rate. Taking into account the OP agreement means that the possible harm is much lower, so reduce the factor appropriately.

Comment: Exactly - 5 times the power requires 5 times the care.